# Replacing a javascript style object in a html string

Tags: reactjs, html-react-parser

Following is my react code block

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
var styles = {
    primaryLable60: {
        fontSize: '60px',
        color: '#dedede',
        direction: 'ltr',
        textAlign: '-webkit-auto',
    }
};
var htmlString = "<div style={styles.primaryLable60}>Hello World</div>";

const renderRoot = document.getElementById('root');
render(
    <div>
        {Parser(htmlString)}
        <div style={styles.primaryLable60}>
            Hello World
        </div>
    </div>
    , renderRoot)
```

I need to get the actual "styles.primaryLable60" style object while rendering.

New to react, so need help on it

Comment: Why are you using `Parser`?

Comment: I do see your code is working as it is here https://codesandbox.io/s/1ozwzn6vo7

Comment: What is the concern?

Comment: I don't think you actually needed any `parser` or `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you know you need to render div so you can put it in jsx and load styles into it. parsers can be useful when your html comes dynamically(may be from backend).

Comment: This is just a sample. Actually the htmlString i am referring above is being fetched from backend

Answer (score 0):

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlString}} />
```

Instead of

```
{Parser(htmlString)}
```

no need to use `html-react-parser`.

may be you have to use if you really need Parser.

```
import Parser from "react-html-parser";
```

[refer here about react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

Comment: If this was the desired output, then really `Parser` is not needed.. React inbuilt support is enough.. That is why I asked the OP what is the reason to bring in `Parser`, I thought may be the OP has something more in mind who knows..

Comment: yeah Parser is no need, if we wants to just display plain text as html elements, dangerouslySetInnerHTML is good enough.

Comment: This is just a sample. Actually the htmlString i am referring above is being fetched from backend

Comment: then also you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML `

Comment: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />  did not solve my problem

Comment: the react -html-parser was also unbale to convert the object to style